# How to get thumbnail of SoundCloud using API?

Tags: soundcloud

For example:

http://soundcloud.com/mhiqu3/sets/heretik/

How to get the thumbnail url: http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000004897289-5r6ws9-large.jpg?1767646

with the api (or without) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `/tracks` endpoint, and read the `artwork_url` property from the returned JSON. More details: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks

Comment: Is there no way but to make an API request every time? Facebook has this graph url that directly just returns a picture...

Comment: As by today Soundcloud tracks html page includes a `og:image` meta tag:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000004897289-5r6ws9-t500x500.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500">`

So now it should be possible to retrieve the artwork without the API using plain PHP or Javascript, even it could be tricky as the header of this page gives an "301 Moved Permanently" HTTP code.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is quite old, but I stumbled in this question looking for something else and I'd like to give my two cents.

These are all possible sizes (source [API Reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#artwork_url)):

> ```
>         * t500x500:     500×500
>         * crop:         400×400
>         * t300x300:     300×300
>         * large:        100×100 (default)
>         * t67x67:       67×67    (only on artworks)
>         * badge:        47×47
>         * small:        32×32
>         * tiny:         20×20    (on artworks)
>         * tiny:         18×18    (on avatars)
>         * mini:         16×16
>         * original:     (originally uploaded image)
> ```

Comment: Just be aware that for some tracks, `original` exists but `t500x500` doesn't, for some the opposite. It's a total mess.

Comment: how is this supposed to be added to the search url ?

Answer (score 9):

also, if you replace the "-large" in the url string with "-t300x300" or "-t500x500" you will have access to the larger formats.

Comment: is there any way to pass parameter for t500x500 image ? 

{{ track.artwork_url }} ?

Comment: This is how I did it `<%= image_tag a.artwork_url.to_s.gsub('-large', '-t500x500') %>`

Answer (score 4):

what you want to do is use Soundclouds API like so:

```
SC.get(PATH, function (track, err){
  IMG_URL = track.artwork;
});
```

you can see an example here:
http://runnable.com/UuiMCfATvMMkAAAS/get-a-tracks-artwork-on-soundcloud-in-javascript#

the PATH to the track can be obtained in different ways 
1. if you know the image id you can grab it like so 
`var PATH = "/tracks" + id;` 
2. if you know the name and user of the track 
`var PATH = "/users/dj-faze/tracks/phase-shift-360-019-degrees"` 
3. you can also get the id with other soundcloud API's

NOTE: Ensure the track's image you are trying to get is public. If it is private your going to have to log in with soundcloud authorization API.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989369/458193) but unfortunately SoundCloud doesn't seem to guarantee that `t500x500`, `original` or other sizes will exist.

So I resorted to writing an express app that redirects to largest available image on their CDN, given `artwork_url`.

**[FixSoundCloudArtworkUrl.js](http://*https://gist.github.com/gaearon/717ed6d6c7771f95d50d)**

It uses their naming scheme and enumerates sizes one by one until some image returns status 200.

Source:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

require('./config/development')(app, express);
require('./config/production')(app, express);

var redis = require('redis'),
    request = require('request'),
    Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

var redisSettings = app.set('redis'),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisSettings.port, redisSettings.host, redisSettings.options);

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
});

function sendError(res, status, error) {
  if (!(error instanceof Error)) {
    error = new Error(JSON.stringify(error));
  }

  return res
    .status(status || 500)
    .end(error && error.message || 'Internal Server Error');
}

function generateCacheHeaders() {
  var maxAge = 3600 * 24 * 365;

  return {
    'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=' + maxAge,
    'Expires': new Date(Date.now() + (maxAge * 1000)).toUTCString()
  };
}

function getCacheKey(url) {
  return 'soundcloud-thumbnail-proxy:' + url;
}

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  var originalUrl = req.params[0],
      cacheKey = getCacheKey(originalUrl),
      urls;

  // https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#artwork_url
  // This is a ridiculous naming scheme, by the way.

  urls = [
    originalUrl,
    originalUrl.replace('-large', '-t500x500'),
    originalUrl.replace('-large', '-crop'), // 400x400
    originalUrl.replace('-large', '-t300x300'),
    originalUrl.replace('-large', '-large') // 100x100
  ];

  return redisClient.getAsync(cacheKey).then(function (cachedUrl) {
    if (cachedUrl) {
      return cachedUrl;
    }

    return Promise.reduce(urls, function (resolvedUrl, url) {
      if (resolvedUrl) {
        return resolvedUrl;
      }

      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        request.head(url, function (err, response) {
          if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            resolve(url);
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        });
      });
    }, null);
  }).then(function (url) {
    if (!url) {
      throw new Error('File not found');
    }

    var headers = generateCacheHeaders();
    for (var key in headers) {
      if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        res.setHeader(key, headers[key]);
      }
    }

    res.redirect(url);
    redisClient.set(cacheKey, url);
    redisClient.expire(cacheKey, 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

  }).catch(function (err) {
    sendError(res, 404, err);
  });

});

app.get('/crossdomain.xml', function (req, res) {
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
  res.end('<?xml version="1.0" ?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" /></cross-domain-policy>');
});

redisClient.on('ready', function () {
  app.listen(app.set('port'));
});

redisClient.on('error', function () {
  throw new Error('Could not connect to Redis');
});

module.exports = app;
```