# Soundcloud 500x500 artwork by default

Tags: php, soundcloud

```
  if($song->artwork_url != null) {
      $song_artwork = $song->artwork_url;
  }
  else {
      $song_artwork = 'img/no_art.png';
  }
```

By default soundcloud pulls `-large` (which is 100x100)

How do i make it pull (t500x500) so i can have a higher res image?

Answer (score 28):

Just replace `large.jpg` by `t500x500.jpg` in the filename, like so:

```
  $song_artwork = str_replace('large.jpg', 't500x500.jpg', $song->artwork_url);
```

In fact, they support a number of different formats for different requests:

```
t500x500:     500px×500px
crop:         400px×400px
t300x300:     300px×300px
large:        100px×100px  (default)
t67x67:       67px×67px    (only on artworks)
badge:        47px×47px
small:        32px×32px
tiny:         20px×20px    (on artworks)
tiny:         18px×18px    (on avatars)
mini:         16px×16px
original:     originally uploaded image
```

I found the documentation in the [Soundcloud API reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#artwork_url), search for `artwork_url`.

Comment: Just be aware that for some tracks, `original` exists but `t500x500` doesn't, for some the opposite. It's a total mess.

Comment: I wrote an [express app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26806356/458193) that redirects to largest non-404 version of the image.

Answer (score 6):

For client side a simple JS `.replace()` will do the job

```
SC.get("/users/984878/tracks", {limit: 10}, function(tracks){

$.each(tracks, function(index,track){

lrgart = track.artwork_url;
lrgart = lrgart.replace('-large', '-t500x500');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

@likeitlikeit's answer worked for me, however I had to change the file extension for the 'original' size to png even though the smaller images were jpg, so try that if your first attempt is not found